# save Jtable data when savebutton is pressed

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I want to save Name and value of jtable into two variable

```
public class NewClass extends JPanel implements TableModelListener {
private final String[] columnNames = { "Name", "Value","check"};
private JTable table;
private DefaultTableModel tableModel;
private final JButton buttonSave;

public NewClass(){
tableModel = new DefaultTableModel(columnNames, 0);

tableModel.addTableModelListener(this);
table = new JTable(tableModel);
javax.swing.table.TableColumn var_col;
var_col = table.getColumnModel().getColumn(2);
final JCheckBox check = new JCheckBox();

var_col.setCellEditor(new DefaultCellEditor(check));
var_col.setCellRenderer(new DefaultTableCellRenderer() {
            @Override
public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table,
Object value, boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int
column) {
check.setSelected(((Boolean)value).booleanValue()) ;
return check;
}
});

JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(table);

setLayout(new BorderLayout());
setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(4, 4, 4, 4));
add(BorderLayout.NORTH, new JLabel("Mon panier", JLabel.CENTER));
add(BorderLayout.CENTER, scrollPane);
//--------I  want to save these Name and value in two variables -----------

Object[] data1 = {
new String("work"), new String("done"),new Boolean(false)};
tableModel.addRow(data1);

buttonSave = new JButton("Save");
buttonSave.setEnabled(false);
buttonSave.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ev) {
    buttonSave.setEnabled(false);
}
});
```

Comment: What exactly is your question? It really doesn't make any sense - sorry.

Comment: actually i have never used Jtable and its time to use it bcz I am getting data(name and values) from serial port and want to show in JTable and also want to save that data when needed.

Answer (score 3):

As discussed in [*How to Use Tables*](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html), your table's data should be managed by a `TableModel` such as `AbstractTableModel` or the concrete `DefaultTableModel` used in your example. In this [example](https://sites.google.com/site/drjohnbmatthews/table), `DataModel` extends `AbstractTableModel` and synthesizes a `List<Value>` of test data; yours would listen to whatever object monitors the serial port. The [example](https://sites.google.com/site/drjohnbmatthews/table) also uses the class `Value` to encapsulate a selectable numeric value. The custom `TableCellEditor` updates each `Value` as it is changed, so the `DataModel` always contains the selection state of each element in the list. Your save button could then save the list elements in whatever format you prefer.